# New to iOS dev: Storyboards or the old-school way?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5, storyboard

I'm gonna give learning iOS development another try. I noticed that w/ iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2 we got Storyboards, I tried it a bit and ah... It's awesome!

So what'd you recommend me to learn first: the old-school way w/ thousands of nibs and alotta code for views or the new & shiny way w/ one Storyboard and code mostly for logic, not views themselves?

Comment: Depends. Do you want to support iOS 4 and lower? If you have loads of screens, you probably want to use multiple storyboards to keep it readable.

Comment: I think storyboards just make the project an entire mess, IMO

Comment: @WTP No, I don't plan to have iOS 4 or lower support. Well just from a perspective of learning, which is better?

Comment: I have the exact same question. Seems like a bad time to be starting to learn iOS and diving into tutorials, because apple just gives a single hello world intro steering me the way of storyboards but then I'm out in the cold. Other tutorials on the web refer to xib files.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should learn iOS dev without Stoyboard. Like just code and Interface Builder. I learned all I know by getting inside a project and go solving all the issues I found mean while I developed it. It's a nice way.